# Email signin email post to firebase from C#

Tags: c#, firebase, post, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to send a post request to Firebase from a C# application which should make firebase send out a signin email to a users email.

I've tried posting from Insomnia to the identitytoolkit.googleapi and it works fine.

but i can't translate the request to C# where i've tried the following:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var obj = new
{
    requestType = "EMAIL_SIGNIN",
    email = $"{user.Email}",
    continueUrl = $"<RedirectToThisPage>?email={user.Email}"
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendOobCode?key=<APIKEY>", json);
responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

This just returns a 404, where Insomnia actually makes firebase send out the email

Comment: You send a POST request but the API key goes into the URL? That looks strange.

Comment: That is how google want it, but yeah it does look strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostAsJsonAsync` implicitly converts the object to JSON, a slight oversight on my part.
So I converted the object to JSON before the POST, and again in the POST request.